# Navigate Directly to Fragment Deep in Screen Hierarchy

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigationbar, android-navigation

I am working on an app that has a tab bar navigation pattern.  Each tab represents a feature of the application that is backed by a ready-only database that is updated daily.  If the data for a feature is not present in the database, I have an `AlertDialog` that prompts the user to update their database from the updates screen.  The `UpdatesFragment` is a sub screen to the `SettingsFragment` which is a top-level option on the tab bar.

What is the best way to show the `UpdatesFragment` directly from the dialog but still show the settings tab as selected and allow the user to navigate back through settings when they press back? Should I go through the `SettingsFragment` and pass an argument for it to directly replace itself with the `UpdatesFragment`?

```
Home | FeatureA | FeatureB | ... | Settings
                                      |
                                   Updates
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd argue that you should let the user update from *any* place, or at least, trigger the update from the AlertDialog itself.

Regardless of that, you want to construct your backstack the same way it would have been constructed if the user tapped all the way to the final destination.

Android provides a [TaskStackBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/TaskStackBuilder.html) for the matter, which you can find in the official Android documentation, located [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/TaskStackBuilder.html).

**UPDATE AFTER YOUR COMMENT**:

Hmmm I see what you mean. Well then you'd have to create fragment transactions and/or use Bundle values to tell the "next" fragment that it needs to open the next and so forth. To be honest, when "shortcuts" like these are needed, there's a possible architecture flaw (no offense) that should rather be addressed before the code starts getting more and more spaghetti.

However, since I don't know your code and your app, I won't judge you :)

What I would do if I were facing this situation, is try to go this route:

Fire an intent to the same activity (so your activity receives `onNewIntent()`) and pass a bundle with the required information for your activity to resolve the intent and fire the correct fragment transactions?

If `UpdatesFragment` should replace settings fragment, then your activity should do either of these upon receiving that intent:

1) Create a Fragment Transaction to replace the current fragment with SettingsFragment.

2) Pass a Bundle to SettingsFragment telling it to open UpdateFragment (and whatever other information is required).

3) Add that to the Backstack.

4) SettingsFragment should check (upon startup) if the args bundle contains such value and should immediately proceed to create another FragmentTransaction to replace itself with UpdatesFragment (and also pass any args in a Bundle that the former may require to perform its actions).

or…

maybe you can try to do all in one step (I'm not sure if this will work, it depends upon your architecture, but it's easy to try).

PseudoCode (assumes you already have your Fragments instances and such)

```
fragmentTransaction
   .replace(your_container, settingsFragment)
   .addToBackStack(null)
   .replace(your_container, updateFragment)
   .addToBackStack(null)
   .commit();
```

Comment: I did not mention that, but the update does start from the alert dialog but the UpdateFragment shows the state and progress of the update.  I took a look at TaskStackBuilder but I am not sure that will work for me since this app has a one activity, with a fragment_container FrameLayout that all the fragments get swapped in and out of.